# dotnet build failed with zero errors and warnings on mac m1

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I try to build my service from the terminal with the `dotnet build` command, I receive this error:

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0-preview-22428-01+14c24b2d3 for .NET

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.00
```

And when I try to run it with `dotnet run --project ...`, I receive this message:

```
The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Interestingly, when I run this service via Visual Studio everything builds and runs okay.

The reason why I need to run it from the terminal is because the project is implemented in a microservice architecture, and in order to lunch it completely I need to run 14 microservices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am having the same issue, seems to be a [bug on .NET 7 RC1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7840)

As a workaround I'm doing the following:

```bash
dotnet build --disable-build-servers
dotnet run --no-build
```

Comment: Thank it works. They also recommend setting `DOTNET_CLI_DO_NOT_USE_MSBUILD_SERVER=1` environment variable, which might be more convenient.